# alexa request token not being passed

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

Really just stunned that something is in the official Alexa documentation, and it doesn't work in code. I am simply trying to create a `list` api, and following: [Alexa NodeJS](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs).

Specifically, [this](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs) section talking about `ListManagementServices` to CRUD with Alexa lists.

If you click the second link I provided, you'll clearly see them state `token can be retrieved from the request at this.event.context.System.user.permissions.consentToken`

OK great, went to my code, plugged in `this.event.context.System.user.permissions.consentToken` only to get an error in cloudwatch saying `can't get consentToken of undefined`. Completely dumbfounded by this, I logged the `this.event.context` to see what kind of object I am working with. Here is the object:

```
{
    "AudioPlayer": {
        "playerActivity": "IDLE"
    },
    "Display": {
        "token": ""
    },
    "System": {
        "application": {
            "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.0beed0e6-51a1-4c6d-ac33-ffc5917865b7"
        },
        "user": {
            "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.AGCMLFZZENPXOPVJNBZYE3MEATUMFIDBZSABYFXORTYX2NH5DYTKR2YGRNEHSKDCQCWA3Q33GIHZIKVI47GON36TEE3XSNXASFYYNS46OXAEAHC3M3QMOFEGH26CCO7VDTEEW5WJW4VIJVYC2XUPHTI73N7ZI5IKH66MOMX5XQTHKUVRLPOAK4ZPJALLZWFJOT4PDQXZP3MVBFA"
        },
        "device": {
            "deviceId": "amzn1.ask.device.AG2Q3NSHYI3KAHOESWBELUSD7GBARMROPJI6NWNWMBHTNGMK3TCKP5PNDAS2AN34JWCCIKURX24EMFCTRMJZGIXSA2YBCSDOOOFQ52PGCZGFDK3RIUE6OK2Z5H7YIYBNBDU7UN5UL2PMXAUEK2IWHILS7SFQ",
            "supportedInterfaces": {
                "AudioPlayer": {},
                "Display": {
                    "templateVersion": "1.0",
                    "markupVersion": "1.0"
                }
            }
        },
        "apiEndpoint": "https://api.amazonalexa.com",
        "apiAccessToken": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjEifQ.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.aKkY8UG0vSs-uP5IoOk-3_MflWI-d9KpIcWSba8YZSEGulOUeyJjHx9qfouOBO3o8WjqeMdLiE1agu6GohXaGeV4jFty9wpg2_Cp_RIAqSpPm-THDt48yRK_6O7PXZjVzgtUUrg81Gi8uceDy7bY42bP7_if5JDpTFLfRxuo7Cj5PmjhqA9aKpdV0PTUWCo6BFrOC9EoNZqjxt-MZrHyR0UQDIO4Ly-y-WfVIf4wqD_VR7YL3f9MW81UcH0XGA6G9_xwvKBsA-VlkideSqudnynM1fUb68HY42qzRn7AzlUPvTcu7ZUuJudc_hTyHDXmcB8J2XBkMWsZJLJCR8NlMA"
    }
}
```

And as you can see, clearly no `permissions` object in the `users` object, and no `token` present anywhere else. The only thing I did see was `apiAccessToken` which when I tried to use that, nothing happened at all. By nothing, I mean, neither of my following console logs were hit:

```
const lms = new Alexa.services.ListManagementService();

  lms.createList(listObj, token)
     .then((data) => {
       console.log(`list retrieved: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
       this.context.succeed();
     })
     .catch((err) => {
       console.log(err.message);
     });
```

Went to the app, no lists were made. I'm assuming it failed? I would have no way of knowing, since neither console log was hit telling me if it was successful or error (assuming an error).

Can someone please explain to me how to get the token needed for this? And do these lists automatically show up in the companion app? I did read somewhere that they should, but again, documentation is not up to date apparently and I just want to know what to expect and how to see if this worked.

Comment: Can't immediately spot anything wrong, but did you make sure to request the list permission when you configured your skill? check [this](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/configure-permissions-for-customer-information-in-your-skill.html) and [this](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/access-the-alexa-shopping-and-to-do-lists.html) from alexa's documentation to know more about lists permissions

Answer (score 1):

the problem here is that you don't have permission for read `list`. For that reason user.permissions.consentToken is undefined
Try downloading the Alexa app, log in with my Amazon user.

Before calling the api, I request the permissions (in this example the card ask for permissions consent for user email)

```
 {"type": "AskForPermissionsConsent",

           "permissions": [

              "alexa::profile:email:read" //replace with the permissions that you need

          ])}
```

The App's home should show a card to give access. So you could get the apiAccessToken and user.permissions.consentToken with the right permissions.